# Android application Lose internet connection once connect to Fiddler

Tags: https, proxy, fiddler, sniffing

I have a strange situation using Fiddler to capture the HTTP/HTTPs traffic from an android application, in general, fiddler works fine, I got everything from any other app as chrome, and more, but this specific app not connect to the internet or lose the connection once I connect to fiddler Proxy server, I don't know why this happened also I don't know if someone has an explanation or got the same issue before, because fiddler in general working, but only this app, once I back to the normal connection and stop connecting to the Fiddler proxy server the connection back to this app.
so if someone has a solution or there is a similar problem as I did not find such kind of problem when I searched it will help.

I use the normal way to capture the data from fiddler by open Fiddler proxy server and connect my Android phone to my PC IP and the port of fiddler app, I was thinking about it and I'm not sure maybe this happened because the app did not trust the root certificate of the https of fiddler or the app protect from sniffing by disconnect the connection once the Android phone use a proxy, I am new using fiddler so I'm not sure how it's going.

I read about also certificate pinning, but I think this is not the case as if it happened it normally connect and show Tunnel or something like this as I understand in the fiddler screen, but not lose the connection.

Thanks in advance.